# Rake - Adding to default task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I am using a third party gem that gives me the ability to execute some tests using the rake command:

```
rake jasminerice:run
```

Is it possible to include the task as part of default rake task? (i.e. when I run `rake` then rake `jasminerice:run` is added to the rest of my tests).  This is required for CI integration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rake, tasks can have dependencies. Generally, you can do this:

```
task :hello do
  puts "hello"
end

task :default => :hello
```

For your specific problem, you should be able to do this:

```
task :default => "jasminerice:run"
```